# Does uses-feature limit App Store Downloads

Tags: android, bluetooth

I can seem to find anything on google, but if i add this setting to my manifest

uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"

will non ble devices such as anything less than 4.3 be able to still download the app off the store?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `android:required="true"` then devices without that feature will not be able to see or download the application from the Play Store.
If you would like the app to be available for devices without that BLE feature then declare the feature with `android:required="false"`. In this case you have to check manually if the feature is available or not.

Please check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html for more details.